# Check if one column value is in another column and create column to indicate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if `A` in `Table1` is found in `A1` in `Table2` and create an indicator column in `Table1` to show this result.

`Table1`:

```
A           B       C       G
Harry       pig     NY      Year1
Kasey       cat     AL      Year2
Ron         b       AK      Year1
Amy         axe     KY      Year4
...
```

`Table2`:

```
A1          Value       
John        X     
Mark        Y   
Harry       Z       
Ron         Z  
...
```

Expected output:

```
A           B       C       G        exists
Harry       pig     NY      Year1    1
Kasey       cat     AL      Year2    0
Ron         b       AK      Year1    1
Amy         axe     KY      Year4    0
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out, using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where)

```
import numpy as np

df1['exists'] = np.where(df1['A'].isin(df2['A1'].unique()), 1, 0)
```

---

```
       A    B   C      G  exists
0  Harry  pig  NY  Year1       1
1  Kasey  cat  AL  Year2       0
2    Ron    b  AK  Year1       1
3    Amy  axe  KY  Year4       0
```

Comment: +1 but in this case we can drop the `where()` and simplify to: `df1['exists'] = df1['A'].isin(df2['A1'].unique()).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge):

```py
out = pd.merge(df1, df2['A1'].drop_duplicates(),
               left_on='A', right_on='A1', how='left') \
    .rename(columns={'A1': 'exists'})

out['exists'] = out['exists'].notnull().astype(int)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
       A    B   C      G  exists
0  Harry  pig  NY  Year1       1
1  Kasey  cat  AL  Year2       0
2    Ron    b  AK  Year1       1
3    Amy  axe  KY  Year4       0
```